# Find all integer solutions for $x*y = 5x+5y$

Tags: diophantine-equations

For this equation  $x*y = 5x + 5y$  find all possible pairs.

The way I did it was:  $x=5y/(y-5)$

And for this I wrote a program to brute force a couple of solutions. If it helps, some possibilities are:  [4,-20], [6, 30], [10, 10]

So my question is: **What is a mathematically correct way to solve this problem?**

Comment: The equation has infinitely many solutions. With your current equation, $x = 5y/(y-5)$, just simply choose a value for $y$, then you will have a value for $x$. Of course, $y$ and $x$ cannot be 5.

Comment: Geometrically its the intersection of rectangular hyperbola with a straight line

Comment: @Tin Phan i think OP wants integers only

Comment: @TinPhan as Archis Welankar said, I indeed only want integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$5x+5y-xy=0$$
$$5x+5y-xy-25=-25$$
$$x(5-y)-5(5-y)=-25$$
$$(x-5)(y-5)=25$$
1) $x-5=1; y-5=25; \Rightarrow x=6; y=30$;

2) $x-5=-1; y-5=-25; \Rightarrow x=4; y=-20$;

3) $x-5=5; y-5=5; \Rightarrow x=10; y=10$

4) $x-5=-5; y-5=-5; \Rightarrow x=0; y=0$

5) $x-5=25; y-5=1; \Rightarrow x=30; y=6$

6) $x-5=-25; y-5=-1; \Rightarrow x=-20; y=4$

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to see, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach can be the beginning of a complete analysis.  We can rewrite $\frac{5y}{y-5}$ as 
$$5+\frac{25}{y-5}.$$
So we get a solution precisely when $y-5$ divides $25$. The only divisors of $25$ are $\pm 1$, $\pm 5$, and $\pm 25$.